# Match pattern and append each line with matched string

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

Match pattern and append each line with matched string until the next match. WES and GET2 is matched in the example below:
I know how to go about one pattern

```
awk '$1~/WES/{A=$1}{print A,$0}'
```

But dont know how to go about two pattern:

Input:

```
WES S1 S2 SET3
S2 S4 S5
D3 D7 F2
GET2 F4 S3 64
SES2 32 Q3
Y67 98 GT1
WES S2 S4 SET3
S2 S4 S5
D3 D7 F2
```

Output:

```
WES WES S1 S2 SET3
WES S2 S4 S5
WES D3 D7 F2
GET2 GET2 F4 S3 64
GET2 SES2 32 Q3
GET2 Y67 98 GT1
WES WES S2 S4 SET3
WES S2 S4 S5
WES D3 D7 F2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk 'match($1,/WES|GET2/){A=substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH)} {print A,$0}' file
WES WES S1 S2 SET3
WES S2 S4 S5
WES D3 D7 F2
GET2 GET2 F4 S3 64
GET2 SES2 32 Q3
GET2 Y67 98 GT1
WES WES S2 S4 SET3
WES S2 S4 S5
WES D3 D7 F2
```

Attaching text in the front is `prepending`, by the way, not `appending` as that is attaching to the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$1 ~ /^(WES|GET2)$/{ p = $1 FS }{ print p $0 }' file.txt
```

Output:

```
WES WES S1 S2 SET3
WES S2 S4 S5
WES D3 D7 F2
GET2 GET2 F4 S3 64
GET2 SES2 32 Q3
GET2 Y67 98 GT1
WES WES S2 S4 SET3
WES S2 S4 S5
WES D3 D7 F2
```

Other variations:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^(WES|GET2)$/{ p = $1 }{ print p FS $0 }' file.txt
awk '$1 ~ /^(WES|GET2)$/{ p = FS $1 }{ $0 = p $0 } 1' file.txt
awk '$1 ~ /^(WES|GET2)$/{ p = $1 }{ $0 = p FS $0 } 1' file.txt
```

Comment: +1 for a nice solution, odd choice to specifically save or print FS though instead of using the comma operator: `{p = $1} {print p, $0}'`